# Possible to get an unrestricted browser console on chrome like you can in firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, console

On chrome apps/extensions one needs to setup many permissions to get access to parts of the API, and some of them are available in apps some in extensions. Is it possible to get an unrestricted browser console [like the one in firefox](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/08/the-browser-console/) with access to the entire API for testing purposes?